# sda1 /puppy_bionicpup64_8.0.sfs not found

Tags: boot, grub, iso, pxe, puppy-linux

I am new to working with linux specially when it comes to remastering. The company i am at has a need/requirement of developing and having the build of a java program in any linux. building the java program isn't a difficulty. But the OS is for me. I started in MX but its size is too big after snapshot. The company loads iso files through memdisk. i remastered a version of puppy linux but it does not load unless usb is attached. its looking for a file in usb while that is also in the iso. i cant even boot the original puppy linux that way. while both original and custom work when booted from usb.

[image: The error message]

[image: loading the iso]

[image: Grub]

Any suggestions on what i can do? can i somehow make puppy iso work with memdisk or should i quit at it and find something else. It can be as simple as updating the grub but i dont know what or how to do it.

What i mainly need is a light OS below 1GB packed a java program in an iso, so computers can be booted on it through lan along with other iso as per need.

Any help or criticization is appreciated as i am stuck .

EDIT:-
image is booted through pxelinux. i did try to follow guide:
http://sirlagz.net/2011/06/13/how-to-boot-puppy-5-2-5-over-pxe/

but still doesnt boot

Comment: I have today encountered this problem. Have you solved this? If you have I would greatly appreciate you posting the solution. If not I would like to know more about your problem. In my case apparently vmlinuz was not able to see the USB flash drive where BionicPup64 was installed. Is your problem the same? I.e., does the directory entry /dev/sda1 exists? Is your installation on an internal hard disk or on an external USB drive. If external is it a flash drive or a hard disk? In my case vmlinuz can see the internal eMMC drive and an external USB hard disk but not the external USB flash drive.

Comment: I noticed that that vmlinuz was able to see a different USB flash drive. So, I installed BionicPup64 to another USB flash drive of the same make and model. This installation works. The interesting thing is the "bad" flash drive was a SanDisk Cruzer Glide and the "good" flash drive was a SanDisk Cruzer Snap. The Snap drives are the cheapest SanDisk drives you can buy. I don't think the Glide drive is bad since Grub2 can read it and BionicPup64 installed on the Snap drive can mount and read the Glide drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change pmedia=cd to pmedia=usb.

also
https://forum.puppylinux.com/viewtopic.php?t=8254
How to boot Puppy over network (PXE / TFTP)? (Solved)
2023-03-15